# What is the proper way to break views into components in Xamarin Forms? How to pass bindings and contexts?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create resuable components, so naturally I want bindings to pass from parent custom view to child and child of child custom views.

To achieve this I don't use MVVM pattern for custom views, but rather use

```cs
BindingContext = this
```

in my custom views constructors.

Of course I would implement BindableProperty for each property I want but oh boy was I surprised by BindableProperty not working at all!
All because of my "BindingContext = this".

Basically each time I have to write my bindings by hands and not by

```xml
<!-- Label in child view -->
<Label x:Name="InnerLabel" Text={Binding LabelText} />
```

I suspect I'm deeply mistaken somewhere, and there is an easier way to break views into smaller hierarchy of parent-child dependent views, without writing huge amount of boilerplate code like

```cs
InnerLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(... etc etc etc
```

How to write reusable views properly in Xamarin Forms? Why my BindableProperty stopped working with BindingContext = this in my custom views constructors?

Comment: you haven't posted any code for your BindableProperty so there is no way for us to tell you what might be wrong.  Generally speaking, any Forms element will inherit it's parent's BindingContext unless otherwise specified.  By assigning `BindingContext = this;` you are breaking that built in inheritance.

Comment: I should mark your comment as right answer. The problem is actually BindingContext = this in custom views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, any Forms element will inherit it's parent's `BindingContext` unless otherwise specified. By assigning `BindingContext = this;` you are breaking that built in inheritance.

Comment: What approach would you recommend to break views into custom components + achieve easiness of using inner context with NotifyPropertyChanged and without cumberstome process of writing declarative binding in constructor for every property?

Comment: I don't know why you can't just declare the bindings normally in XAML  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#create-a-custom-control

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason properly mentioned in the comment section, the problem with

```cs
BindingContext = this
```

inside custom views constructors.

In chase for easy way wanting to use {Binding CustomViewProp} I was breaking chain of parent -> child context, making BindableProperty properties to receive nothing from parent contexts.

THE PROPER WAY TO USE CUSTOM VIEW PROPERTIES IN XAML, example:

```xml
<ContentView x:Name="Self" ... ... ... all other initializing parent element stuff

<Label Text="{Binding CustomViewProp, Source={x:Reference Self}}" />
```